# I am trying to implement Permisions in asp.net boilerplate webApi

Tags: asp.net-core, aspnetboilerplate, abp

I am trying to implement an AppService called Plug, I want to use User Role and Permissions and I can't seem to get it working, I applied the steps above and I am not winning.

```
namespace Sprint.Plug
{
    [AbpAuthorize(PermissionNames.Pages_PlugEntity)] //Permisions
    public class PlugAppService: AsyncCrudAppService<PlugEntity, PlugDto, Guid>, IPlugAppService
     {        
       public PlugAppService(IRepository<PlugEntity,Guid> repository):base(repository)
       {

       }        
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you applied the permission to the database for your user/role in AbpPermissions table?
if you are already authenticated and you consume that API, [AbpAuthorize(PermissionNames.Pages_PlugEntity)] attribute will check you have permission in table AbpPermissions isgranted or not.

Ex :
[image]

Comment: How do you apply them?